# I have two api call second is depend on first api call respose

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios, react-query

I want to get coordinates first from the geolocation API and then fetch weather conditions with the help of coordinates that I got from the first API call.

```
   const { data: cords } = useQuery("cords", () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    });
   });

  const { isLoading, isError, error, data } = useQuery(["weather"], () => {
    return axios.get(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=myapikey`
    );
  });
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2):

For the second query you have to use the `enabled` [operator for dependent queries](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/dependent-queries).

You can do `enabled: !!cords` so it gets executed when there’s `cords`.

Edit:

In your case it'd be like this:

```
  const { isLoading, isError, error, data } = useQuery(["weather"], () => {
    return (
      axios.get(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=myapikey`
      ),
      {
        enabled: !!cords,
      }
    );
  });
```

This way the second query will only fire when the `cords` have a value and it will fire every time `cords` value it's updated.